# sum specific elements of a dataframe with iloc

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very simple dataframe:

```
    Data = {'Month': ['Jan ','Feb ','Mar ','Apr ','May ','Jun '],
        'Bill': [1500,2200,3500,1800,3000,2800],
        'Maria': [3200,4100,2500,3000,4700,3400], 
        'Jack': [1700,3100,3300,2700,2400,3100]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(Data,columns=['Month','Bill','Maria','Jack'])
```

I would like to choose and sum specific selections from this data frame. E.g. when I use

```
1.    df.iloc[:,2]
```

I get the entire second column, without the column headers. Easy now to use

```
2.    sum(df.iloc[:,2])
```

to get the sum of the second column. However, when I use

```
3.    df.iloc[0:,1:3]
```

I get the two columns of data, AND the headers. Now, when I use the sum operator:

```
4.       sum(df.iloc[0:,1:2])
```

I get the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'". This makes sense; there is after all a string in the header. So, I switched notation to :

```
5.    df.iloc[0:,1:3].sum()
```

and this works fine.
My question is - why does expression 1 give me only the data without the header, but expression 3, gives me the column name as well. I was hoping to get only the data in the next columns, not the headers, and then be able to sum a specific set of numbers, without having them grouped as happens in expression 5. What am I missing?
Thanks

PS - if a picture helps, I just want to select the circled/highlighted data. I thought since expression 1 got me data for "Bill", without the column header, expression 3 would get me more columns but without the column headers.

[image]

Comment: `df.iloc[:,2].sum()`.  `df.iloc[:, 2]` returns a Series.  `df.iloc[:, [2]]` returns a DataFrame with one column. Expression three returns multiple columns, i.e. a DataFrame. You can also use `df.iloc[:, 1:3].to_numpy().sum()`.

Comment: @Alexander - thanks; and I think that's where my confusion is....is there a way to get the data across multiple rows and columns as a series instead of a dataframe? Say I just want to only get the highlighted numbers in the picture (posted a little later), not the column names.Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: `df.iloc[1:5, 1:3].to_numpy()`

Comment: @Alexander - genius...I've no idea why it works...but I'll take it. Thanks!

Comment: Pandas is basically a wrapper around numpy arrays. Pre pandas 0.24, one would use `df.iloc[1:5, 1:3].values` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code:

```
 df.iloc[1:5, 1:3].to_numpy()
```